# Remove hyperlink in GI

Tags: acumatica

After creating GI, it will automatically make some related columns as hyperlink which one can click and directly open respective screen. How do we get rid of that hyperlink?

For example- 
Create a new GI with SOOrder table and add OrderType, OrderNumber and CustomerID fields in ResultsGrid. View GI, it will have hyperlink for all the three columns. I do not want to see the hyperlink for Ordertype and CustomerID.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In result Grid Tab Unckeck the box(Default Navigation) for fields you don't want hyperlink